# JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Array" against Fetch API request

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, expo, fetch-api

I am trying to make an HTTP request using Fetch API as follows:

```
const collectTargets = () =>{fetch('REQUEST URL?', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    request_type: "osm_points",
    lat: region.latitude,// coming from region state 
    lng: region.longitude,
    limit: 5,
  })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
}
```

I receive an error as follows. Can some one kindly explain it me. I saw some post saying API must be down etc, though does not seem the case here.

```
JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Array"
* [native code]:null in parse
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: You are not getting a json response so you can't use `.json`. Check the response you get with the developer tools or changing `.json()` to `.text()`.

Comment: @RolandStarke Ok I see, it returns some string "Array" and not JSON as desired

Answer (score 0):

Note - : //must you need to use `wp_die();`  otherwise it's return with 0 and error in response .

```
$output = array("status"=>'success', "content"=>$content);

echo json_encode($output);
```

I am sure [here](https://sknetking9.blogspot.com/2021/03/how-to-call-ajax-in-wordpress.html) your problem will solved.

https://sknetking9.blogspot.com/2021/03/how-to-call-ajax-in-wordpress.html

Comment: If you are linking to your own site or service, you need to be explicit about it. Please review [How not to be a spammer.](/help/promotion)